# How to pass UIImage in tap gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

problem os to pass image in gesture that not work, i want to pass image with tap gesture and that image is used in other purpose..

```
func addGestureToImageView(imgView:UIImageView) {
let tapGesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.tapImage(tap: ,img:imageview)))
    imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture1)
}
```

that function call in tap gesture..

```
func tapImage(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer,img:UIImage) {
   viewDisplay(img:img)
}
```

i want to use that image..please provide a solution.

Comment: `if let imgview = tap.view as? UIImageView { // Do something }` to get current view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9960512/4376861

Comment: Hope this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299162/pass-extra-argument-for-uitapgesturerecognizer-with-selector

Comment: nirav how its comes as duplicate,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly get the image from imageview

```
  func tapImage(_tap:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   if let getImage = tap.view as! UIImageView
    {
          viewDisplay(getImage:img)
      }

}
```

for sample

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self. tapImage(_:)))
imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

and handle the action as

```
func tapImage(_ tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   if let getImage = tap.view as! UIImageView
    {
          viewDisplay(getImage:img)
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)


 func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
 {

  let tappedImageView = gestureRecognizer.view!
  let imageView = tappedImageView as! UIImageView
  print("image ---%@",imageView.image!)
 }
```

Comment: you need to modify your answer, if you are using like this `#selector(imageTapped))`, then you need to call the function as like `func imageTapped
 {` not `func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
 {`

Comment: Thanks  But we can also use this